# Accepting orders for processing large tasks in background from REST api in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, batch-processing

I need some sample projects for accepting request for doing very time consuming tasks in background. I have a REST endpoint which receive request for doing large task processing and I need to save these requests in a database table with SUBMITTED status and return the id and status to the api client. After task completion, I need to change the status to DONE or ERROR.

Comment: Are you asking for how to handle long running requests? Look at implementing a callback if so. Question is unclear though. Perhaps you can clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Submit those task using Executorservice via implementing Runnable interface, and let them run.
If you want some output about the task completion status then submit those task with Future<> by implementing callable interface and retrive the status by future.get().

Please elobrate your question with examples if it still not resolved.